# ProcessBuilder and command with space

Tags: java, processbuilder

I recently updated my Java version to JDK7u21. In the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime) of update 21, it is clearly mentioned about issue using Runtime.exec.

I therefore want to change my code to use ProcessBuilder. I am trying to execute a command with spaces in it. But even if using ProcessBuilder for this, I land up in C:\Users\Parag.Joshi\Documents and not the exact directory.

Below is my code:

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "explorer ", "C:\Local Disk D\My Tutorial");
p.start();
```

I had a look at [Java execute a command with a space in the pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916918/java-execute-a-command-with-a-space-in-the-pathname) but didn't get a clue.

Comment: No putting quotes around doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested it on my local machine.

the behaviour is caused because of the space after `"explorer "`. remove that space and it will work. Also you need to quote the `\`.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "explorer", 
                                      "C:\\Local Disk D\\My Tutorial");
```

Comment: Perfect! Yes, I forgot to escape \. I had escaped it in my code although. But it is a space problem after explorer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Sure you did escape `\\` otherwise the code wouldnt't have executed and shown you the home dir, i added it just for the sake of completeness ;-)