# Close browser window using java code

Tags: java, browser, using

How should i close an opened browser window using java code. I have found a way to first find the process then end that process. Is there any better way? I have opened the browser initially using the below code. I am working in CentOS.

```
String url = "http://192.168.40.174/test15.html";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + url);
```

Comment: Browser windows do not equal processes.

Comment: @user207421 Where is it stated that a window is a process? It is only mentioned that you are able to close a window through a process, not that they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("killall -9  firefox");
```

change the name of the browser according to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can put it in a `Process` and kill that.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runtime.exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + url);
p.destroy();
```

-- update --

You should execute your command with a String array

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
    "/usr/bin/firefox",
    "-new-window", url
});
```

This is less prone to errors:
[Java execute a command with a space in the pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916918/java-execute-a-command-with-a-space-in-the-pathname)

Or use `ProcessBuilder`: [ProcessBuilder Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: Note that if the user opened additional windows while in that browser, all the windows will end up being destroyed, not just one.

Comment: @Jelle ..tx for your answer but using runtime its takes alot of time to open the browser so now i am using the belwo code to open browser. in this case what could be a appropriate way to close the opened browser other than finding the process and then closing it.Any suggestion ?     Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
                         //dt.browse(  new URI(url) );

Comment: @PinkGiraffe Not that I know of. Maybe you should find out why your `Runtime` is acting slow.

Answer (score -2):

I was trying to achieve a similar thing, without caring too much which browser will open. I come accross a solution based on Java FX:

```
public class MyBrowser extends Application {

private String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842930/close-browser-window-using-java-code";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(url);
    webview.setPrefSize(1800, 1000);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
    stage.show();

    //stage.close();

}
```

}

Of course if you call `close()` this way, you will not really see the embedded browser window. It should be called in another part of the code, e.g. in response to a button push.