# Close the current browser tab programmatically

Tags: javascript, java, browser

I am working on a spring based application. My Scenario is as follows :-

User pastes a URL from clipboard to a browser tab (new/existing),hits return key and a particular JSP is rendered in the browser tab.
The user can now view the relevant information.
There is back button on this page, on click of which some logic is executed at the server side and the current  browser window should close.

I have seen 2 approaches on internet.

1.Use javascript window.close() on click of button. Not working as "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it".

2.Use something like this
[Close browser window using java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842930/close-browser-window-using-java-code)
But what should be the exact command to be executed.

Please let me know if there is any other way possible also??

Comment: Instead of closing. could you go back in history? `window.history.go(-2)`

Comment: `window.close()` - Have you tried that?