# Java exec mount with sudo and file path spaces

Tags: java, linux, sudo, mount

My question is a combination of sorts of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916918/java-execute-a-command-with-a-space-in-the-pathname) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java). I want to mount a file with spaces in its path with sudo permissions, as such:

```
sudo mount /path/to/mount/point /dir\\ with/spaces\\ in\\ name
```

If there's no spaces in the paths, I can just do this, since this user has sudo permissions for the mount command:

```
Runtime.exec("sudo mount /path/to/mount/point /dir/without/spaces");
```

But there are spaces, so I tried:

```
Runtime.exec("sudo mount /path/to/mount/point /dir\\ with/spaces\\ in\\ name");
```

This gave me "Unrecognized arg '\'" or something to that effect from mount. Surrounding the pathnames with single or double quotes also didn't work.

Then I tried:

```
Runtime.exec("sudo", "mount", "/path/to/mount/point", "/dir with/spaces in name");
```

which of course fails because sudo wants some method of password entry, even though I don't normally need to enter a password for sudo mount. Faaantastic.

This seems like a catch-22 to me. I can get sudo working if I go with the single String method, or I can get the pathnames working if I go with the String array method. How do I get *both* working?

Answer (score 1):

Single backslash cannot be written verbatim in string literal. Backslashes should be escaped, so use `\\`:

```
Runtime.exec("sudo mount /path/to/mount/point /dir\\ with/spaces\\ in\\ name");
```

As for the password, `sudo` may not ask for password if recently you entered it on the same shell. If you want to allow to mount given path without superuser permissions (for regular user) edit its `/etc/fstab` entry as shown [here](https://superuser.com/q/174776/269881).

Add `user` to its options, e.g.:

```
/dev/sda8    /media/foo    ext4    rw,user,exec 0 0
```

and then add privileges to read and write:

```
# chmod a+rw /media/foo
```

Then your line can be:

```
Runtime.exec("mount /path/to/mount/point /dir\\ with/spaces\\ in\\ name");
```

or

```
Runtime.exec("/bin/mount", "/path/to/mount/point", "/dir with/spaces in name");
```

or alike.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And sorry, I was in a hurry yesterday and forgot to escape my backslashes: that wasn't the problem I was running into. I've tried every combination of single, double, and even triple backslashes ("\\", "\\\\", and "\\\\\\" in Java terms), but unfortunately none of those work. Sudo also has to stay in there, because the account I'm running this from has sudo permission for mount but not regular permission, and I don't have control over that. It's a very particular set of constraints, I know.

Comment: You want to `sudo` without supplying user password?

Comment: Basically I need a solution which both allows paths with spaces and doesn't require me to supply the password. I already have the mount command set up with NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers for this account.

Comment: I'm just guessing: `Runtime.exec("/usr/bin/sudo","/bin/mount",...);`. You have to say something more on the result (process output? error message?) than just "does not work".