# How to run Ubuntu commands from java

Tags: java, ubuntu

currently I am trying to give terminal commands, the code is below:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c","hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/new_cur2/* > /home/leo/new_cur2.csv"});
```

It is giving me the error exit: 127
Can anyone fix it please?

Many thanks

Comment: You could try splitting the command into separate strings, afaik that is a requirement any ways.

Answer (score 0):

From this [127 Return code from $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from) the error code means the command is not found in your path. Make sure your PATH is correctly setup.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but the path is correct, if I put the command part hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/new_cur2/* > /home/leo/new_cur2.csv   in terminal, it will work

Comment: Because when I was trying to run the command in Java, if I want to create a shell, it is necessary to use "/bin/bash","-c".   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916918/java-execute-a-command-with-a-space-in-the-pathname