# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() ignore path spaces

Tags: java, unix, macos-sierra

I've got a problem that I haven't seen anyone else come across, and that is using exec() to execute a Unix command, but with a variable path rather than a fixed one, when it contains spaces. Most solutions I've seen to paths with spaces in them involve manipulating the string, which I can't do equally with this. Here is my code.

```
void launchApp(String appName) {//TODO ignore spaces in names!
    String[] cmd1 = new String[] {"chmod +x ", (new File(dataPath(""))).getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath() + "/" + appName + "/" + appName + ".app/Contents/MacOS/" + appName + ""};
    String[] cmd2 = new String[] {"open ", (new File(dataPath(""))).getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath() + "/" + appName + "/" + appName + ".app"};
    saveStrings("log0", cmd1);
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        println(e);
    }
}
```

(Don't question the really complicated paths... they work just what I need to finish this prototype :) there would be variables to work around anyway)

By the way, I realize I can use ProcessBuilder rather than Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and I've seen that as a solution to the problem, but I have tried it and it doesn't work. I just have it in the exec() format while posting this.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Possible related: [Spaces in java execute path for OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697621/spaces-in-java-execute-path-for-os-x).

Comment: @devpuh different problem, my path contains (many) variables and can’t be solved in that way.

Comment: Have you read all answers? Please try to simplify `cmd1` and `cmd2`. For example `String path = new File(dataPath(""))/*...*/;String cmd1 = {"chmod", "+x", path};/*...*/Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);`

Comment: @devpuh thank you for your help, after rereading some similar questions I was realizing I was using PathBuilder incorrectly (like PathBuilder("chmod +x", path) rather than separating "chmod" and "+x"), and now it does correctly ignore spaces in the path.